# Alternative to Visual Studio C# in Linux for Hardware Interfacing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, qt, .net-core, monodevelop

I have been using Visual Studio (VS) with C# for a while to code software for the automation of research experiments. Basically, the control of different hardware and the data acquisition from cameras and DAQ cards. It can include also the communication to a couple of server computers to which some equipment are connected. I am very happy with the performance of C# and the easy to program the GUI with VS.

Now, I am starting a new project, similar task, but I want to program everything in Linux, to be fully open source and take advantage of the command line for some things. I would like to stick to C# if I had a similar environment as VS, but in Linux.

**1) Could you recommend me what is the best option to build GUI-based software in Linux with C#?**

**2) The performance would be similar to using QT and C++?**

**3) What of the two options would you choose and why?**

Answer (score 1):

1) Take a look at [Vala language](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala). Vala syntax is similar to C# and GUI applications can be created with GTK-3.0 binding.

[valadoc.org](https://valadoc.org) contains documentation for most (if not all) of supported libraries.

2) Both Qt/C++ and Vala is finally compiled to native code. Vala code is translated to C before compilation. Correctly written application should not suffer from any performance issues in vala, nor in Qt/C++. I have written networking project both in vala and qt. All works correctly.

3) I'm afraid cant answer. Read about both solutions and decide what suits your project better.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a multiplatform IDE to compile C# Ithink your best bet is monodevelop http://www.monodevelop.com/

You can try visual studio code https://code.visualstudio.com/ from its name you can understand this is a "derivative" from visual (by MS) (but quite different different from the original) but this run on multiple platforms.

or gnomebuilder https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder (but in this one C# and vala are second class language)